# Office UI Fabric React - Show tooltip when form input is focused?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-fabric

This is what I currently have:

```
<TooltipHost
  content="Enter claim name in a way to be understandable for all parties."
  directionalHint={DirectionalHint.rightCenter}
  calloutProps={{ calloutMaxWidth: 100}}
>
  <TextField />
</TooltipHost>
```

The tooltip is shown on hover. I want it to be exclusively shown on focus. 
Is there a way to do it without controlling it with state?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The host automatically adds it to hover and focus. If you want focus only you'd need to use the Tooltip control itself and manually show it on focus.

Comment: not true. use calloutprops--> hidden prop to control the tooptip visibility.